# ion-datetime give 31 days for all the month in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have used ion-datetime to display date of birth,but it display 31 days in February as well as all other 30 days month ,here is my code in ionic 4

```
  <ion-item class="formGroup">
      <ion-label position="floating">Date of birth</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime display-format="DD/MM/YYYY" picker-format="DD MM YYYY" formControlName="dob" no-padding>
      </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

hear is app screenshot
[image]

Comment: No. That is working fine. Without any issue.

Comment: i have attached my screenshot please check it.

Comment: Can you please replicate same issue in stackbliz?

Comment: i know i am working on two project right now in ionic 4 one shows this bug and one does not so i don't understand this problem is there any solution for it.

Comment: If you can shows where it is not then we can help you.

Comment: It's ok I have solved this issue after updating my ionic version ,thanks a ton.